# How to group entries by month (from a date field) when `only_full_group_by` is on?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Example table:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| payment | date                |
+---------+---------------------+
|      20 | 2021-02-03 12:00:00 |
|      40 | 2021-02-02 12:00:00 |
|      30 | 2021-01-01 12:00:00 |
|      60 | 2020-02-02 12:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Desired output would sum up payments from each month.

```
+----------+---------+
| total    | month   |
+----------+---------+
|       60 | 2021-02 |
|       30 | 2021-01 |
|       60 | 2020-02 |
+----------+---------+
```

I have some older code that successfully outputs this result by grouping them by a formatted date, so it uses the `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')` as the grouping condition.

It looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(`payment`) AS total, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m') AS month
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

But when `only_full_group_by` is on, this no longer works, complaining that:

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Doing `GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date)` produces the same result.

While grouping by `date` only would execute, but would result in an incorrect output as it wouldn't sum up the two entries from `2021-02` together.

Is this something that `only_full_group_by` shouldn't even allow in the first place? Or if it should, then how would I write this statement correctly to continue outputting the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . The problem is the `date` in the `ORDER BY`. A simple workaround is:

```
SELECT SUM(`payment`) AS total, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m') AS month
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC;
```

I used `month` in the `GROUP BY` as well, because MySQL conveniently allows that syntax.

Or, if you prefer:

```
ORDER BY MIN(`date`)
```

The bare `date` is not available for the `ORDER BY` because it is not in the result set generated by the `GROUP BY`.